# How can I bind the navigation bar with json Object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a static navigation bar in HTML. Now I want to bind it with json data. I have fetched the json data but was unable to bind with navigation bar in html.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav_li"><a href="#home" class="active"><p class="hello"> </p></a></li>
</ul>
<script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(function(v,i)  {
    var news = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_li")[0];
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
     p[i].innerHTML  = v.title;
     news.appendChild(p);

     console.log(v.title);
    })
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

request.send()

</script>
```

Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at template3.html:358
    at Array.forEach ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload (template3.html:354)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code. Inspect the content of news.

Comment: How can i improve the code? I have inspect the news but unable to find out error.

Comment: You need to check where do you want to append the dynamic elements. It is under news or p. Also you are iterating the response and trying to access p[i] , which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create LI node & text node and append to UL

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(function(v, i) {
      console.log(v.title)
      var node = document.createElement("LI"); // Create a LI node
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(v.title); // Create a text node
      node.appendChild(textnode); // Append text node to LI node
      document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].appendChild(node);
    }); // Append li node to UI
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

request.send()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>mobiForge Web share API Demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav_li">
      <a href="#home" class="active">
        <p class="hello"> </p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check your code ... you need to properly close the  `forEach` function

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
p[i] = ....
```

this is not a correct way to create element.

`p` is a `HTMLCollection` map to the `DOM`, but it will not change `DOM` itself. It just like a view layer.

I am not very clear about you `DOM` struct. These code may be helpful.

```
function createMyElement (content) { 
  console.log(content);
  // create a new a tag
  var newA = document.createElement("a", {href: "#home", class: 'active'}); 
  newA.setAttribute('class', 'active');
  // create a p tag with content
  var newP = document.createElement("p"); 
  newP.setAttribute('class', 'hello');
  newP.innerHTML = content;
  newA.appendChild(newP);  
  return newA;
}
const news = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_li").item(0);
data.forEach(function(v,i)  {
  // create a element
  let a = createMyElement(v.title);
  news.appendChild(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#home" class="active"><p class="hello"></p></a></li>
</ul>
<script>
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)
    request.onload = function () {
        // Begin accessing JSON data here
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            data.forEach(function (v, i) {
                var news = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_li")[0];
                //var p = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
                //p[i].innerHTML  = v.title;
                var p = document.createElement("LI");
                p.innerHTML = v.title;
                news.appendChild(p);

                console.log(v.title);
            })
        } else {
            console.log('error')
        }
    }

    request.send()

</script>
```

Comment: appendChild method accepts a object type 'node'. refer this to more details. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Answer (score 0):

### use document.createElement

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!---  ul for links ---->
        <ul id="navlinks"></ul>
            <script>
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
            request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)
            request.onload = function() {
              // Begin accessing JSON data here
              var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
              if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                data.forEach(function(v,i)  {
                //console.log(v)        
                let ul = document.getElementById("navlinks"); 
                // dynamic li creation 
                let li =  document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = v.title;
                ul.appendChild(li)
                })
              } else {
                console.log('error')
              }
            }
            request.send()
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it to reproduce what you seem to be aiming for:

```html
  <ul class = 'nav'></ul>

  <script>
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

    request.onload = function() {
      // Begin accessing JSON data here
      let data = JSON.parse(this.response)
      // query the unordered list element / node
      let list = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0];

      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // range through the data
        data.forEach(function(value, index)  {
          // create a list item element
          let listItem = document.createElement("li");
          // add a class = 'nav_li' to list item
          listItem.classList.add('nav_li');
          // create an anchor link
          let link = document.createElement('a');
          // if it is the first value of the json object, add href = '#home' and class = 'active' to link
          if(index === 0) {
            link.setAttribute('href', '#home');
            link.classList.add('active');
          } else {
            link.setAttribute('href', '');
            // alternatively
            // link.setAttribute('href', value.url);
          }
          // create an empty paragraph
          let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
          // add a class = 'hello' to the paragraph
          paragraph.classList.add('hello');
          // set the text of the paragraph to title from json object
          paragraph.textContent = value.title;
          // nest the pragraph inside the anchor link
          link.appendChild(paragraph);
          // nest the anchor link inside the list item
          listItem.appendChild(link);
          // add the list item to the unordered list
          list.appendChild(listItem);
        })
      } else {
          console.log('error')
        }
      }
      request.send()
    </script>
```

1. You can still use `var` instead of `let`
2. Query the list element once, outside the `forEach` function
3. It helps to name your variables clearly.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1: Using `appendChild`**

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
let ul = document.getElementById("navlinks");

request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

request.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(v => {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = v.title;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    })
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

request.send();
```

```html
<ul id="navlinks"></ul>
```

**METHOD 2: using `innerHTML`**

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
let ul = document.getElementById("navlinks");
let li = '';

request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

request.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(v => {
      li += `<li>${v.title}</li>`;
    });
    ul.innerHTML = li;
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

request.send();
```

```html
<ul id="navlinks"></ul>
```